# How to convert x86_64 64-bit register names to their corresponding 32-bit register names in GNU assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I would like to clear upper 32 bits of x86_64 64-bit general-purpose registers in GNU assembly (I use the GNU assembler 2.25.2). Operations that output to EAX register clear upper 32 bits of RAX register.

```
mov    eax, eax
```

A macro can be used to generalize it for all x86_64 64-bit general-purpose registers.

```
.macro ClearUpper32bits register64
    mov  register32, register32
.endm
```

The issue is how to get the corresponding 32-bit register name of a 64-bit register name. One solution is switching operands in the macro in accordance with each register name.

```
.macro ClearUpper32bits register64
    .if (\register64 == rax)
    mov    eax, eax
    .elseif (\register64 == rbx)
    mov    ebx, ebx
    (Repeat the two lines for RCX ... R14 registers)
    .elseif (\register64 == r15)
    mov    r15d, r15d
    .endif
.endm
```

This is redundant and easy to make mistakes in copying the lines. Is there a better way than this macro?

Comment: Invoke the macro with the 32 bit name already ;)

Comment: According to [Agner Fog's microarch pdf](http://agner.org/optimize), mov-elimination in Intel IvB and later CPUs (zero latency and no execution unit needed, handled at register rename time) never works when src and dst are the same register.  So when convenient, it's actually better to MOV to a different register to zero-extend a value.  Just write a comment on the MOV instead of writing a macro around a common one-instruction idiom, IMO.

Comment: Also, how did the value end up in the register so that the top 32 bits are not already zeroed? Is that a common occurrence?

Comment: Thank you, Peter Cordes, I will check the PDF later.

Comment: Thank you, Jester. In my environment, "mov reg64, reg64" clears the non-zero top 32 bits of the reg64. CPU-Z reports my CPU to be Intel Core i3-4160 3.60GHz, Haswell, Family 6, Model C, Stepping 3, Ext. Family 6, Ext. Model 3C, and Revision C0.

Comment: The assembly in my comment is wrong. It is what I meant that "mov eax, eax" clears the upper non-zero 32bits of RAX register in my environment.

Comment: It does, no question about that. The question is, why you need it. How come you need to zero the top bits, how did you load the value into rax such that the top bits are not zero. Maybe **that** part should be fixed instead.

Comment: I confirmed Agner Fog's microarch pdf, pp. 127. Haswell has the same mov-elimination behavior.

Comment: What I want to do is to handle multiple 32-bit bitmaps fast. Let's say an XMM register holds 4 x 32-bit bitmaps and I need bitwise OR of the four bitmaps. One solution is moving them from the XMM register to 64/32-bit registers and executing ORs for them. In my understanding, Jester's suggestion is using PEXTRD twice and using OR for two 32-bit registers holding two bitmaps rather than using PEXTRQ once, splitting the two bitmaps (64 bits) into two 64-bit registers (upper and lower 32 bits), and using 64-bit OR for them as I do now.

Comment: Not sure I follow you. You say you have 4 bitmaps but then talk about just two? Anyway, whatever you want to do, just make sure the last GPR operation is on 32 bits and so you will get the top bits cleared automatically.

Comment: I should have written "using PEXTRD and OR four times" and I understand Jester's advice. By the way, I write assembly code with nested macros that take 64-bit register names as their parameters. It is convenient to assign registers at most outer macros and to propagate the registers to their inner macros. Just in case replacing 64-bit to 32-bit register names in the outer macros does not work when I fix my code, it is helpful to convert 64-bit to 32-bit registers in a macro locally.